# python not using tkinter 8.6 installed with homebrew on Mac

Tags: python, tkinter, homebrew

I am using python 3.9.1 on Mac OS 10.15.7 (Catalina).  Python was installed with homebrew. When I import tkinter, I get version 8.5.9, and I want version 8.6 instead.

`brew info tcl-tk` gives

```
tcl-tk: stable 8.6.10 (bottled) [keg-only]
Tool Command Language
https://www.tcl-lang.org
/usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.10 (3,022 files, 50.9MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2020-03-10 at 17:57:25
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/tcl-tk.rb
License: TCL
==> Dependencies
Required: openssl@1.1 ✔
==> Caveats
tcl-tk is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have tcl-tk first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/saul/.bash_profile

For compilers to find tcl-tk you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include"

For pkg-config to find tcl-tk you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/pkgconfig"

==> Analytics
install: 362,394 (30 days), 390,184 (90 days), 474,512 (365 days)
install-on-request: 9,609 (30 days), 17,845 (90 days), 60,715 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

I put the suggested lines in my `bash_profile` but they don't seem to have had any effect.

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tcl = tkinter.Tcl()
>>> print(tcl.call("info", "patchlevel"))
8.5.9
```

I found a lot of stuff about this issue online, but it all seemed to be related to pyenv, which I don't use, and I couldn't pick out anything other than what's described above that seemed to related to my situation.

What do I need to do?

**EDIT**

I tried adding the lines to my .bashrc file also, but that had no effect.

Comment: Are you installing it on the system and using a virtualenv from before the patch ?

Comment: @Alex I'm not using a virtualenv at all.

Comment: [Tk](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) should be a newer version, i cant realy see why it is happening, a kinda promising idea is delete the brew version and install it from the python web site, i imagine it is similar to the problems i had with conda on windows and it was conda itself adding problems.

Comment: Are you using virtualenv? What's path to your tinker module that you import in python (you can check that by using this - path = os.path.abspath(a_module.__file__))?

Comment: @DolidodTeethtard Thanks, but I'm not using virtualenv, and I as I said in my answer, this issue is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently my python was outdated.  (I never thought of that, since it was from last month.)  Anyway,

```
brew update && brew upgrade python@3.9
```

fixed things.

Answer (score 2):

Brew itself provided solution with python 3.9. You just have to install separate package:

```
brew install python-tk@3.9
```